# Error stopping service postgresql-x64-9.4

Tags: windows, postgresql, server, postgresql-9.4, windows-server-2016

I'm new in postgreSQL. and I have some issue when I want to uninstall my postgreSQL in windows server 2016.
I have error message **"error stopping service postgresql-x64-9.4"** on my windows server 2016. I want to re-install because when I installed PostgreSQL, I have error message **"Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly. The database cluster initialisation failed".**

**Error message install PostgreSQL**
[image]

**Error Uninstall**
[image]

kindly need your help to solved this.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

solved.
you can add new user on computer management, give "member administrator" and "power users". install run as different user and enter your username and password.

Comment: I tried adding a different user. Installing as postgre (with administrative privileges), setting the local to something other than default, etc.  I cannot get around this issue at all. I have exhausted every recommendation that I have found.